# How to solve undefined reference to a function

Tags: c, gcc, g++, mingw

I am trying to run this code simple.c in this link [zfp](https://github.com/hansenms/ZFP/tree/master/examples) on windows by using this command
`gcc -o a simple.c`
please is that correct because I got on these errors:

```
simple.c: In function 'compress':
simple.c:39:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'stream_open'; did you mean 'zfp_stream_open'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   stream = stream_open(buffer, bufsize);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
            zfp_stream_open
simple.c:39:10: warning: assignment to 'bitstream *' {aka 'struct bitstream *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   stream = stream_open(buffer, bufsize);
          ^
simple.c:66:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'stream_close'; did you mean 'zfp_stream_close'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   stream_close(stream);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   zfp_stream_close
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `zfp_field_3d'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `zfp_stream_open'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `zfp_stream_set_accuracy'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `zfp_stream_maximum_size'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `stream_open'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `zfp_stream_set_bit_stream'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `zfp_stream_rewind'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `zfp_decompress'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `zfp_compress'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `zfp_field_free'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x1d5): undefined reference to `zfp_stream_close'
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\cceazl20.o:simple.c:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `stream_close'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All these functions found in zfp.h file and this file in the same folder of simple.c but I can not reach to it.
Please can you help me how to use zfp on windows?
Thanks in advance.?

Comment: have you tried adding the zfp_ prefix to the stream_open and stream_close function names on lines 39 and 66 respectively?

Comment: It's not enough to `#include "zfp.h"`. You need to link the library. You'll need to add something like `-lzpf` to your compiler options (at the end).

Answer (score 0):

ZPF is supposed to be a library. Just including the header file won’t compile your code. You would need to link the library.

I checked the git repo linked by you, as on main repo page you check all the installation steps are given.

Also the library is to used on linux or OS X as mentioned in readme of the repo.

Steps to follow:

1. Run`make` in main repo directory
2. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to lib folder created by the above make command
3. Now run `make test`

This will create executable file inside examples directory of all programs present in examples.

Check below the screenshot from readme of the repo.
[image]